# getting shorturl with yourls api

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, yourls

Is there a way using javascript/jquery to have a short url returned with the yourls API, where if I send a URL, if there is already a shorturl created it just returns the ShortURL if not, it creates a random one and then returns that newly created one?

I've read all the API I can, but it is not indepth enough to figure that out, so I'm wondering if anyone who has done this knows where I can find that specific documentation.

I want to allow people that have a long url to click a link and get a short url returned, which if it already exists, I don't want it created again.

I would appreciate your tips/advice if you have the know how.

Thank you kindly,
-Richard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is rather targeted towards the YOURLS backend. I can confirm that if you are using a recent version of YOURLS, on default there will be no duplicate short URLs. If you are submitting a long URL more than once, the API will still return the same short URL (to your Javascript client).

You can find that setting in the `config.php` on your YOURLS server:

```
/** Allow multiple short URLs for a same long URL
 ** Set to true to have only one pair of shortURL/longURL (default YOURLS behavior)
 ** Set to false to allow multiple short URLs pointing to the same long URL (bit.ly behavior) */
define( 'YOURLS_UNIQUE_URLS', true );
```

**So be sure that setting is set to `true`.**

---

To help get you started, here's an easy way to create short URLs using Javascript. I'm using [this third party wrapper](http://neocotic.com/yourls-api/) for YOURLS.

You will need to connect to your server with a username/password or alternatively your [signature token](https://github.com/YOURLS/YOURLS/wiki/PasswordlessAPI):

```
var api = yourls.connect('http://your.server/yourls-api.php', {
  username: 'admin',
  password: 'qwerty'
});
```

If the connection is up, you can use `.shorten()`:

```
api.shorten('https://yourverylonglink.com/toshorten', function(data) {
  console.log(data.shorturl); // returns http://your.server/1234
});
```

Comment: so if it does not exist, it creates it, if it does exist it returns it? I don't see that in that wrapper, explained that way, so asking if you know it does or not. thank you for your answer. :)

Comment: I got it. So in this code:
'api.shorten('https://yourverylonglink.com/toshorten', function(data) {
  console.log(data.shorturl); // returns http://your.server/1234
});'

I would simply create a var like this, right:
var Short1 = api.shorten('https://yourverylonglink.com/toshorten', function(data) {
  console.log(data.shorturl); // returns http://your.server/1234
});

Comment: Yep, you can also create a function with that code that takes the long url as an argument and then `return`s the short url.

Comment: Just getting a javscript error in the console that says: "yourls is not defined"

Comment: You need to include the yourls wrapper from here: https://github.com/neocotic/yourls-api/releases

Comment: I have it doing this:
<script>
var api = yourls.connect('http://myshortlinkMadeUpURL.us/yourls-api.php', {
  username: 'admin',
  password: 'ppassssworddd'
});
// fake data above, I used the real data..
function YoursAPI(api,shurl) {
var theshurl = api.shorten(shurl, function(data) {
  console.log(data.shorturl); // returns http://your.server/1234
});
return theshurl;
}
</script>
Short URL 1: <script>document.write(YoursAPI(api,'[LinkCode]&pid=170'));</script>
Short URL 2: <script>document.write(YoursAPI(api,'[LinkCode]&pid=171'));</script>

so not sure why it is not working.

Comment: So by using the wrapper, you mean, pull in the require right? like script src="/path/to/yourls.js", etc, right?

Comment: Fabian, it is returning this in the HTML: [object Object] - not the short url. How do I display it? I cannot get it to work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127001/discussion-between-richard-jones-and-fabian-schultz).